# how to open Gmail inbox and readmail with selenium tool

Tags: selenium, gmail, inbox

i' m testing my web application with selenium. When a user registered, an activation link will sent to user mail id. now i' m able to login to gmail account and unable to pen inbox using selenium. Is there any solution to solve this problem?

thank in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I came across this blog post which may help you - http://seleniumsoftwaretesting.blogspot.com/2011/08/verify-email-confirmation-using.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need gmail for that? If there is activation link sent to specified e-mail, what about trying other service for e-mail? I have been playing around with gmail via Selenium IDE and did not found any solution...

Comment: the following code work fine for me.. open http://gmail.com
// do the login stuff, click on login
waitForElementPresent canvas_frame
selectFrame canvas_frame
waitForElementPresent //div[@class = 'y6']/span[contains(., 'subject_here')]
clickAt //div[@class = 'y6']/span[contains(., 'subject_here')] 0,0
// do stuff you care about

Comment: I have since learnt that Mailinator offer a good service. If your emails do not contain any sensitive data it is a very good disposable email provider.